# Drag and drop with not regular grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I need your help. I have to implement functionality like on picture.[image]

I need to take item from item list and drag it into right container cell. Also when it is in cell in grid user could have ability to remove item from grid and put it into items list. Also when I drop item on grid it should change position to be in center of cell.
I was trying jquery UI but I was not able to create all functionalities. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: What code have you got already, and what functions are they missing?

Comment: I don' have any code. I was trying with two sortable list connected together but these three boxes at the bottom are not going to work well